# Nunit Assertions - Assert.False(true) vs Assert.True(false)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

New to unit testing, and am a little confused on what the difference between `Assert.False(true)` vs `Assert.True(false)` would be?

Could someone explain how these are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are guaranteed to fail.

`Assert.False` passes if the argument evaluates to `false`, which `true` does not.

`Assert.True` passes if the argument evaluates to `true`, which `false` does not.

The difference is what condition makes them pass, but when passing a constant as your code does; it just means a guaranteed failure. They also have different semantic meaning (for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 3):

Both `Assert.True(false)` and `Assert.False(true)` will cause the test to fail.  They both can be read like "Make sure this value is true, if it's not then fail." and "Make sure this value is false, if it's not then fail." respectively.  So whatever the condition/value in your assertion is, it must evaluate to the respective value or the test will fail.